# Link to report without report ID

Tags: url, custom-reports

Is there a way to create a relative URL link to a report? For example, a link that would be valid in test, QA, and prod. Since the report ID would be different in each environment, would need a way to find the specific report without the report ID, such as by report name.
So, two requirements:

1. relative URL link, and
2. to a report using non-ID value, such as report name.
   Suggestions?
   Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Have you looked into Custom Settings or Custom Metadata Types?

Comment: Use CMDT to save the report Developer Name and then query for the Id

Answer (score 0):

You would need some code to help you, but the level of effort is trivial.

```
<apex:page controller="ReportRedirectController" action="{!redirect}"></page>
```

```
public class ReportRedirectController {
    public ApexPages.PageReference redirect() {
        String reportName = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('report');
        Report r = [SELECT Id FROM Report WHERE Name = :reportName];
        ApexPages.PageReference ref = new ApexPages.PageReference(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+r.Id);
        ref.setRedirect(true);
        return ref;
    }
}
```

Now, you can use it anywhere Visualforce is valid, with a URL like `/apex/Report?report=Name+Of+The+Report`.

Error handling and unit testing is left as an exercise to the reader.